# I m trying to build a 2*2 array but my program asks for 5 inputs. Why?

Tags: c, for-loop

I couldn't zero down where i have missed in the input statement. I have build it to acquire four values as input but it goes one more.

manipulating the array entries to check if the fifth value is stored. Basic things

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i,j,a[2][2];
   for(i=1;i<=2;i++)
   {
     for(j=1;j<=2;j++)
        scanf("%d\t",&a[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n%d\t%d\n%d\t%d", a[1][1],a[1][2],a[2][1],a[2][2]);
}
```

Comment: When you declare an array with two entries, like `a[2]`, the only valid indexes are 0 and 1. But the loops and the printf are using indexes 1 and 2. One solution is to make the array bigger `int a[3][3]`.

Comment: In C the array starts at 0 not 1, so the declared array `a[2][2]` contains `a[0][0]` upto `a[1][1]`.

Comment: `a[1][2]` and `a[2][1]` and `a[2][2]` do not exist. Your array has 4 elements: `a[0][0]`, `a[0][1]`, `a[1][0]`, and `a[1][1]`.

Comment: thanks for the advice... but It doesn't seem to work that way.. it is what we define in the for loop as i am able to get the results as expected. When i printed, a[0][0]..a[1][1], all values except a[1][1] had zeroes..

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
  int i,j,a[2][2];
  for(i=0;i<2;i++) /*go through rows - arrays in c go [0- (n-1)]*/
  {
    for(j=0;j<2;j++)/*go through col */
       scanf("%d",&a[i][j]); /*remove \t- now will scan 4 values only */
  }

  printf("\n%d\t%d\n%d\t%d", a[0][0],a[0][1],a[1][0],a[1][1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. the tab was trouble some '\t'. I have one more q. when i added one more matrix with the '\t' say b[2][2] in the same program(int i,j,m,n,a[2][2],b[2][2], then the fifth value that got entered after a[1][1] appeared as the first value in the b[0][0]. Where was it stored then?(should i specify the code?)

Answer (score 4):

You have declared this

```
int a[2][2];
```

which has four items, `a[0][0]`, `a[0][1]`, `a[1][0]` and `a[1][1]`.

However, you are starting your indexing at `1` and going up to `2`, so are stepping out of bounds which is undefined behaviour. 
Anything can then happen.

Change your loops i.e.:

```
   for(i=0;i<2;i++)
   {
     for(j=0;j<2;j++)
     // as you were
```

to index from 0.

You also need to consider your `printf` statement, since that oversteps too.

Comment: Thanks for the help,. when i tried with my original program, i mean for(i=1;i<2;i++), i still get the results with a comment as such " *** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated Aborted (core dumped)".. Why is that so? should i understand something more?

Comment: When you tried what with your original program? Have you sorted the `printf` statement? If you have a core dump, you can load it in the debugger to see what went wrong where. Concentrate on making sure you don't try to access `[2]` in `a` - for either index though.